# Error flags resulting from MPI call

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, runtime, mpi, hpc

I am receiving an mpi error from the following call MPI_IRECV when using a large number of processors (~1500). My code is compiled with error checking flags (bounds checking etc) and each mpi call has a subsequent error check. The ierror returns a large 9 digit number rather than any of the standard error messages. The majority of the processors pass the error check though. Is getting a garbage error message indicative of a certain type of error in my code? Perhaps the MPI call is stepping out of bounds? Thanks

```
  kk = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Do i = 1,nprocs                                                                                                                                                                                        

     isrc = i-1                                                                                                                                                                                          
     idest= mype                                                                                                                                                                                         
     itag = isrc*nprocs + idest+1 + tag_offset    

     If (commatrix_send(i).gt.0) Then                                                                                                                                                                    
        kk = kk+1                                                                                                                                                                                        
        isize = 3*commatrix_send(i)                                                                                                                
        call MPI_IRECV(to_be_sent(1,1,kk),isize,                   &                                                                                                                                     
             MPI_INTEGER,isrc ,itag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,                &                                                                                                                                     
             recvrequest(kk),ierror)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        call checkMPIcall(ierror,__FILE__,__LINE__)                                                                                                                                                     
     End If                                                                                                                                                                                              
  End Do                                                                                                                                                                                                 


  ll = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Do j = 1,nprocs                                                                                                                                                                                        

     isrc = mype                                                                                                                                                                                         
     idest= j-1                                                                                                                                                                                          
     itag = isrc*nprocs + idest+1 + tag_offset                                                                                                                                                             
     If (commatrix_recv(j).gt.0) Then                                                                                                                                                                    
        ll = ll+1                                                                                                                                                                                        
        isize = 3*commatrix_recv(j)                                                                                                                                                                      
        Call MPI_SSEND(to_be_received(1,1,ll),isize,MPI_INTEGER,   &                                                                                                                                     
                       idest,itag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        call checkMPIcall(ierror,__FILE__,__LINE__)                                                                                                                                                     
     End If                                                                                                                                                                                              
  End Do
```

**UPDATE**

Error output

135932164 Invalid tag, error stack:
MPI_Irecv(165): MPI_Irecv(buf=0x7d52b88, count=3, MPI_INTEGER, src=1433, tag=2111740, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request=0x7e4d548) failed
MPI_Irecv(109): Invalid tag, value is 2111740

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I have added a bit more of the code to help describe my problem a bit better

Comment: `MPI_Error_string` may be what you're looking for

Comment: Note the default error handler for MPI routines (MPI I/O excepted) is MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL, so unless you have changed that MPI_SSEND won't return on error, it will just abort. See e.g. https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_mpi/mpi_error_functions.html. As for out of bounds we can't see if you don't show us the bounds - complete program, please!

Comment: @IanBush        call mpi_errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_ERRORS_RETURN, &
     &                         ierr) is called beforehand

Comment: @ptb looking at the error string now

Comment: @IanBush Bush please see the error output that I have added

Comment: @ptb Bush please see the error output that I have added

Comment: OK. It says you have an invalid tag. From what you have shown it is not possible to work out what the tags even are. Please, PLEASE show a COMPLETE program which demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: which MPI library (vendor & version) are you using ? you might want to write a simple program that check the maximum allowed tag in your environment.

Comment: is there any rationale for *encoding* **both** source and destination in the message tag ? at first glance, encoding only the sender rank is enough but might not even be necessary.

Comment: My guess would be that there is a limit on the tag imposed by your MPI librabry, especially as the problem only occurs with a large number of cores. Maybe you can check the MPI library for such constraints and try using another scheme to assign the tags.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes you were right, it was the MPI_TAG_UB, it was set to 2^21 on the hpc I was using. Rewriting how the tag is computed. Thanks everyone for your comments and suggestions